# SQL question, regarding removing records in a new table from an existing table

Tags: sql

My problem:  I have a master (large) table 'Contacts'.  I have created a new (smaller) table 'Unsubs'.  My goal is to remove all rows in 'Unsubs' from 'Contacts', and have it update the existing 'Contacts' table (so not create a new table). 'user_id' is the common attribute.

I have tried this code below and some similar variations, however the query continues to time out.  I attempted a Left join as well but I don't think it meets my requirements.

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts c
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id
                      FROM Unsubs u
                      WHERE u.user_ID = c.user_id)
```

Expectation - if 'Contacts' is 200k, and 'Unsubs' is 1k, 'Contacts' would result to be 199k (if all user_id's found a match).

Comment: You mention both updating and removing rows.  Then you show a `select` query.  I'm lost on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud, where only select statements are allowed.  I am am trying to work around this limitation in order to remove rows in the 'Unsubs' table from the existing 'Contacts' table.  Hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned UPDATE & DELETE but show a SELECT-Query. Here is an option for all of them (yes, LEFT JOIN should work):

```
SELECT * FROM contacts c 
    LEFT JOIN Unsubs u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE u.user_id IS NOT NULL

UPDATE c.myField = u.myField FROM contacts c
    LEFT JOIN Unsubs u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE u.user_id IS NOT NULL

DELETE FROM contacts c 
    LEFT JOIN Unsubs u ON c.user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE u.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Upvote for the two examples of UPDATE / DELETE with LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

i prefer not exists

```
SELECT c.* FROM contacts c
  WHERE  NOT exists
 (SELECT 1 FROM Unsubs u WHERE u.user_ID = c.user_id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
update contacts
    set is_active = 0
    where not exists (select 1 from unsubs u where u.user_id = c.user_id);
```

Then when you query contacts, you would use something like this:

```
select c.*
from contacts c
where is_active = 1;
```